# bash: Declare local variable in the for expression

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

This function:

```
function prova {
    for (( i=1; i<=5; i++ )); do echo test; done
    return $?
}
```

Returns:

```
test
test
test
test
test
```

This other instead:

```
function prova {
    for (( local i=1; i<=5; i++ )); do echo test; done
    return $?
}
```

Returns:

```
bash: ((: local i=1: syntax error in expression (error token is "i=1")
```

Is it possible in bash, as in other languages, to declare a variable as "local" on the fly, in the for expression?

Comment: Usually `local` variables can be defined in code blocks, like `functions`.

Comment: `(( ))` can only evaluate arithmetic expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read [Bash: What does “masking return values” mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/506355/338177):

> When you declare a variable as either local or exported that in itself is a command that will return success or not.

> So if you wanted to act on the return value of your command [...], you would be unable to since it's going to exit with 0 as long as the local declaration succeeds (which is almost always will).

```
function prova {
    local i=1
    for (( "$i"; i<=5; i++ )); do echo test; done
    return $?
}

prova

test
test
test
test
test
```

Comment: Shellcheck is going to warning about masked values, `sudo apt install shellcheck`, and then `shellcheck yourscript`.

Comment: looks a bit strange, nothing wrong but ... `local i; for ((i=0;...))` feels better.